# Trouble mocking SqlConnection for Unit Tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, sqlconnection

I am calling code that I cannot change that takes in a `SqlConnection` and a `Transaction` created from that `SqlConnection`. I am attempting to mock this `SqlConnection` using Moq 4.16.1. I am getting the following error when attempting to unit test the code:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IDbConnectionProxy' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

I have wrapped the `SqlConnection` in my own wrapper to try to get this to work, but this has not helped.

`SqlConnectionWrapper`:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Wrappers
{
    public class SQLConnectionWrapper : ISQLConnectionWrapper
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

        public SQLConnectionWrapper(string connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public IDbConnection Open()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
private Mock<ISQLConnectionWrapper> _mockSqlConnectionWrapper;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _mockSqlConnectionWrapper = new Mock<ISQLConnectionWrapper>();

    var mockSQLConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
    mockSQLConnection.SetupAllProperties();

    _mockSqlConnectionWrapper.Setup(x => x.Open())
        .Returns(mockSQLConnection.Object);
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to mock the IDbConnection interface, what's the point of `ISQLConnectionWrapper` and `_mockSqlConnectionWrapper` ?

Comment: `calling code that I cannot change that takes in a SqlConnection and a Transaction created from that SqlConnection.` in that case you *can't* just mock `IDbConnection`. The code expects the connection and transaction to behave in very specific ways. It's far easier to test using a test database anyway, eg using LocalDb. If the code expected an abstract DbConnection or even the ancient `IDbConnection` interface, you could use a connection to eg an in-memory SQLite database

Comment: I'm with PK on this one; unit testing code that uses concrete DB classes with mocks is a dead end. Either rewrite the code under test so it uses abstractions and not concrete classes (and ideally it would then not even refer to databases, but to higher level interfaces, e.g. `IMyDataLayer.InsertUser` or somesuch) or use automated tests but then use [database projects](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools) to deploy an actual database locally. Be prepared for much worse running times for tests though, as the DB has to be recreated for at least every run, if not every test.